# Fullcalendar two events per day

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I´m using A JavaScript event calendar. Customizable and open source. https://fullcalendar.io/

Is it possible to set a maximum of two events per day in fullcalendar?

I know that it is possible to set only one event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic & http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/ In the homepage demo you can see there are 7 events on 7th November.

Comment: yes. I know! But i want to set a limit of 2 events per day.

Comment: did you try setting [`eventLimit`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/) to 2?

Comment: Do you mean you want to a) limit the number of events which can be displayed on a particular day, or b) limit the number of events the user can create on any given day? If it's a), then eventLimit will work as suggested by Karsten (in the month view, at least)

Comment: No it´s b). The user has only the month-view. And he should be able to drag ´n drop external events to a day, but not more than two events per day.

Comment: for that you'll have to write some custom code which runs in the eventRender callback and checks the date of the event, and counts the other events on the calendar on that day, and returns false if the number of events that day is already 2. (hint: you can fetch all events on a particular day using the clientEvents method with a custom callback). If you can't figure that out let me know and I can potentially help with an example.

Comment: Hi ADyson, thanks for that answer. I didn´t know how to use clientEvents method to get the number of events on a day. It were nice to get an example.

Comment: @AlexanderMenger I've added an example answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventReceive callback runs when an external event is dropped on the calendar and has been rendered. When this happens we can use the "clientEvents" method to check how many events are already present on the day the external event was dropped on, and decide on that basis whether to remove it from the calendar.

```
eventReceive: function(event) {
  var newEventDay = event.start.startOf('day');
  var existingEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", function(evt) {
    //this callback will run once for each existing event on the current calendar view
    //if the event has the same start date as the new event, include it in the returned list (to be counted)
    if (evt.start.startOf('day').isSame(newEventDay)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  //if this new event means there are now more than 2 events on that day, remove this new event again (N.B. we must do it like this because by this point the event has already been rendered on the calendar)
  if (existingEvents.length > 2) $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", function(evt) {
    if (evt == event) return true;
  });
}
```

N.B. This assumes that the events you're dragging don't span more than one day. If they can, you'll need to alter this code a bit and bring the end date into the equation as well.

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfm1odm1/2/

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for that answer. It works, but there is a little mistake. If I drag more than two events on a day, all events are invisible.

Comment: @AlexanderMenger you're right, that is an issue. Had a think, and the only way round this is to use a different approach, via the eventReceive callback. Within eventRender there's no way to distinguish between the just-dropped event and other existing events, which was what was causing the problem. I've updated the answer to the new approach, and also provided a working example to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: @AlexanderMenger did this altered version work for you? If so, please remember to accept the answer - thanks.

Comment: yes it´s working fine. Where do I accept the answer? I can only vote for it?

Comment: Oh okay, I just found it!