# Full Calendar revert an external drop event

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm a complete beginner regarding the Full Calendar, so apologies for a possible simple question.
I am trying to revert a drop from an External Event. If I use the revertFunc(), the event snaps back to it's original position in the list but the event is still on the calendar until it is refreshed. Ideally I would like it to disappear as soon as the dialog box is closed. This is the code

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) 
{
  var tag = $(this).data('event').tag;
  var eventDate = $(this).data('event').projectDate;
  var calDate =  date.format();

  if (tag == PSTag) 
  {                                              
    if(eventDate != calDate)
    {
      alert('You must drop the event on the correct date'); 
      revertFunc();
      return;
    }
    var eventObjectId = $(this).data('event').schWork;
  }

  if (tag == WOTag) 
  {                                              
    var eventObjectId = $(this).data('event').workorder;
  }

  var title = $(this).data('event').title;
  alert(tag);    
  updateCalendarEvent(eventObjectId, date.format(), resourceId, tag, title);  

  if (tag != PHTag) 
  {                                              
    $(this).remove();
  }    
  setupDraggableEvents();
}
```

Many thanks for any assistance

Comment: the "drop" callback doesn't have a revertFunc function available to it. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/. You're thinking of "eventDrop" which is fired when dragging and dropping internal events

Comment: To remove an external event which has been dropped on the calendar, you need to handle the eventReceive callback, and actually delete the event. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159861/fullcalender-two-events-per-day/47175973#47175973 . The conditions for deletion are different but the principle, and the act of deleting, is the same.